# Java outputs references

Tags: java

I have a bit of a difficult time wrapping my head around this so I hope you guys can help me out here. Why does a[0] get replaced with 400 in this example here

```
int [] a = {1, 2, 3 } ; 
int [] b = a ;
b[0] = 400 ;
System.out.println(a[0]);
```

while in the example here c remains 2? I just don't understand this.

```
int c = 2 ; 
int d = c ;
d = 1 ; 
System.out.println(c);
```

A short explanation as to why this is happening would be very welcome.

Comment: It's the difference between reference values (in the first case) and primitive values (second case).

Comment: By the way these are two different scenarios. To be equal, the first example should have `b = {5, 6, 7}` instead of `b[0] = 400 ;`. And you would notice that it behaves the same, so `a[0]` remains `1`.

Comment: Reassigning a variable is different from altering an object referenced by a variable.

Answer (score -2):

In java, here the same array has two references a and b, so whatever changes you do to b reflect in a as well. You may say, a and b are two alias here for one and only one instantiated array.

Arrays are also objects and their super class is Object class in java.
From the [JLS Section 4.3],

> There are four kinds of reference types: class types (§8), interface
> types (§9), type variables (§4.4), and array types (§10).
>
> In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are
> dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object
> (§4.3.2). All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array.